# Could not find videos taking space on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, storage

I am always running out of space on my iPhone (SE, 64Gb, iOS 12.1.2). I tried to managed everything managed via the "Settings > General > iPhone Storage" but there seems to be some *media* files I could delete.

When I connect my phone to iTunes, I can see that it is 10 video files, taking up more the 41 Gb of space, but impossible to locate them. I have no downloaded video on Netflix, Video, etc, ...

Screenshot from itunes:
[image]

Screenshot from the "Iphone storage" from the "Settings" on the iPhone
[image]

Any idea where these files could be? And how to delete them?

Comment: What does the storage screen on the phone itself show?

Comment: Same thing, with "media" instead of "video". And none of the listed applications below take that many space (the largest one being a game of 2Gb). I added the screenshot to the question.

Comment: The application list actually would be the interesting part :-) but if none of the apps uses more than 2 GB it probably isn‘t that important

Comment: None do... The largest one is 2Gb, then the next ones are all below 300Mb... And I clearly do not have enough application to make it up to 40Gb

Comment: it might be that your iTunes purchases of podcasts or videos are syncing to the phone and taking up space. Please check that and turn it off in iTunes preferences-> devices. and  in iTunes preferences->sharing and in iTunes preferences-> store. 
do respond after all three trials .